# WIndows Forms Host Background buggy

Tags: wpf

I am having an issue with the WinFormsHost control in my WPF application.

I didn't know to to describe it 100% by myself so I made a video to help me:

https://youtu.be/KpcWdPCmahI

Whenever I try to set a `Brush` whose `Color.Value.A` property's value is 255 (FF in hex) to the Background property of my WinFormsHost, the color is reverted immediately.

In other words you may know the `Colors.White` would return a `Color` with the value `#FFFFFFFF`. The background would revert back to the previous color went attempting to set this.

However if I set the `Color`'s A (Alpha value to 254 aka `#FEFFFFFF` The color is set without reverting to it's previous color.

I wrote this to try and work around this weird behavior (working right now)

```
private void ColorPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color?> e)
{
    Brush brush;
    if (e.NewValue == null) return;
    if (e.NewValue.Value.A == 255)
    {
        var color = Color.FromArgb((byte) (e.NewValue.Value.A - 1), e.NewValue.Value.R, e.NewValue.Value.G,
            e.NewValue.Value.B);
        brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        ((ColorPicker) sender).SelectedColor = color;
    }
    else
    {
        brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)e.NewValue);
    }
    WindowHostControl.Background = brush;
}
```

Comment: I watched your video, read your description, and have no idea what the problem you are trying to fix is. Perhaps if you elaborate, include code, and describe what the problem is?

Comment: Updated, thanks :) I hope this explains a bit better.

Comment: What happens when you set the background of the control inside the WindowsHostControl instead of the background of the WindowsHostControl itself? I've never had problems setting the background of WinForms controls used in WPF before. How about hard coding the color, to test whether it is a bug in your combo box logic?

Comment: @user3690202 Hi there, the control inside the host is simply a `Windows.Forms.UserControl` that is used to inject the visuals of a UI framework known as `Perspex`. I do not want to change the background of the child because that would defeat the coloring options might set for the control being developed. (This is basically a Visual Studio designer type thing)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the system that was in place for the designer was not fully understood, I was assigning the color incorrectly.

The entire view you see in the designer area is a `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`. The solution was to set `ControlStyle.AllPaintingInWmPaint` to true and set the `UserControl.BackColor` during the `OnPaint()` call.